# Order of casting in nested select

Tags: sql-server

I'm facing a strange issue. I've to queries that, should give the same result (all FieldX are of type text):

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(myfield as varchar(max)) AS smallint)
  FROM (SELECT [Field1] AS myfield
          FROM [iPad-CC].[dbo].[ZZZ_IMP_TEMP]
         WHERE [Field0] IS NULL) as base
 WHERE myfield IS NOT NULL

SELECT myfield
 FROM (SELECT CAST(CAST([Field1] as varchar(max)) AS smallint) AS myfield
        FROM [iPad-CC].[dbo].[ZZZ_IMP_TEMP]
       WHERE [Field0] IS NULL) as base
 WHERE myfield IS NOT NULL
```

While the first work fine, the second one throw a 245 error (unable to convert varchar type 'dummy' to smallint).
Ok, 'dummy' is in a row where Field0 is not null, so seems that the CAST take place for every row regardless of WHERE clause (query optimizer non very clever...), and the error makes sense.
What doesn't make sense is why, if i remove the last WHERE clause, everything goes fine without errors (but unfortunately I also get unwanted rows):

```
SELECT myfield
 FROM (SELECT CAST(CAST([Field1] as varchar(max)) AS smallint) AS myfield
        FROM [iPad-CC].[dbo].[ZZZ_IMP_TEMP]
       WHERE [Field0] IS NULL) as base
```

Of course this is a small piece of complex stored procedure and using the first query would lead to much more code (because the inside SELECT is a variable used in various dynamic queries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

**and Field1 IS NOT NULL**

```
SELECT CAST(CAST([Field1] as varchar(max)) AS smallint) AS myfield
FROM [iPad-CC].[dbo].[ZZZ_IMP_TEMP]
WHERE [Field0] IS NULL
    AND Field1 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Not so easy because Field1 is not defined in inner SELECT. This works, but considering that I've about 100 Fields is really a huge overhead: "SELECT myfield
 FROM (SELECT CAST(CAST([Field1] as varchar(max)) AS smallint) AS myfield, Field1
   FROM [iPad-CC].[dbo].[ZZZ_IMP_TEMP]
  WHERE [Field0] IS NULL) as base
 WHERE Field1 IS NOT NULL'

Answer (score 0):

It is because the query optimizer tries to apply the conditions (in your case `myfield IS NOT NULL`) on the innermost sub-queries.

That actually will help a lot with performance, but in situations like this, will break the query because it will try to `CAST` the value and check the conditions on values that you expect not not come out of the sub-query.

UPDATE:

you can assume that your original query is translated to this one:

```
SELECT myfield
FROM (SELECT CAST(CAST([Field1] as varchar(max)) AS smallint) AS myfield
     FROM [iPad-CC].[dbo].[ZZZ_IMP_TEMP]
     WHERE [Field0] IS NULL AND 
     CAST(CAST([Field1] as varchar(max)) AS smallint)IS NOT NULL) as base
```

Comment: Good point, but I've no mean to change the inner query because it's also part of other dymanic SQL queries. I'll go with a variant of mehdi lotfi's solution

Comment: this was not the solution. I just wanted to answer the question. The query I gave you will still not work, It's just there to clarify why you get that error.